# Getting error message when opening report server home page ( found 163 but 162 needed)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs

I just uninstalled SQL Server reporting services native and installed back again from same media which we used 3 years ago. This version is free one (development use only). I configured the report server but am now getting following message.

> The version of the report server database is either in a format that is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is '163'. The expected version is '162'. (rsInvalidReportServerDatabase)

Here is the current version of SQL Server info.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR) (KB3194721) - 11.0.6248.0 (X64) 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Please help how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you checked - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/upgrading-to-sql-2014-report-server-version-mismatch/

Comment: Have you tried applying SP3 to RS? Looks like SQL is running that, but your install probably doesn't have it.

Comment: Your SSRS is 3 years old, but your SQL server is updated sometimes after last November? Like the error says, the database is newer than SSRS expects

Comment: Was Reporting Services working before you uninstalled it? What was the reason for uninstalling and reinstalling? Are you then pointing it to a ReportServerDB that already exists?

Comment: Hi @seventyeightist, it was but my manager was unable to create another instance of ORG_MSCRM(Dyamics CRM 2015 on-prem.) We were getting following error. "Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: Wrong number of tasks found for roleContent Manager, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details.;"

Comment: hi @Kin, you are right if we upgrade from 2012 to 2014..but I just installed the RS and Installed back again in 2012 itself

Comment: I am not sure how good this is but I ran following command "
Update ServerUpgradeHistory
set ServerVersion = 162
where UpgradeID = 2"

Comment: I wouldn't recommend updating "system" tables (upgrade history etc) directly, since although it may no longer complain about the 162/163 incompatibility, you may run into other (more subtle) issues.

Comment: What version number are you now on for Reporting Services? - Start the Reporting Services Configuration manager. On the Report Server Status page, view the Product Version value. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630446(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53205/discussion-between-seventyeightist-and-user2040021).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talked through with the Asker in chat but in essence:

Database Engine (SP3) and Reporting Services (RTM) are now installed on the same server but experiencing incompatibility since the "naïve" Reporting Services (installed from a RTM media - overwriting the now-uninstalled updated version) is seeing a more recent (updated) Database Engine ReportServerDB version than it can handle. Database Engine has been upgraded since the original install (via Windows Update or whatever applies to that environment) to SP3 but RS has now been reset to "naïve" RTM version.

Update the installed Reporting Services with SP3 and any CUs to match the installed Database Engine version, restart and re-try. There may be some downtime for users depending on whether it requires a restart so advise/schedule that accordingly.